# Export specific columns of data from range to text file

Tags: excel, vba

I export Excel data to a text file. It works when I export all range data (ex. `"B2:E" & p`).

For some cases, I need only B & E column data.

```vb
Sub make_textfile()

'Variable declarations
Dim myFileName As String, rng As Range, cellVal As Variant, row As Integer, col As Integer
Dim inputNumber As Long
inputNumber = InputBox("Please enter number : " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "It may be 30 or 50 or your custom number! ", "Insert Data")
'Full path of the text file
myFileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Text_1.txt"
'Data range need to write on text file
p = inputNumber + 1
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E" & p)
'Open text file
Open myFileName For Output As #1
'Number of Rows
For row = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    'Number of Columns
    For col = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
   
    cellVal = rng.Cells(row, col).Value
    'write cellVal on text file
    If col = rng.Columns.Count Then
        Print #1, cellVal & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    Else
        Print #1, cellVal & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    End If
    Next col
Next row
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the loop parameters by setting the columns to be processed:

```
For Each col In Array(1, rng.Columns.Count)
```

instead of `For col = 1 To rng.Columns.Count`

Since the variable in the [for each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) loop must be a Variant for arrays, change the `col As Integer` declaration to `col As Variant`